# Is there a performance penalty for parsing .ts files VS .d.ts files?

Tags: typescript

This question originates from this change:

> I just realized that there is no good reason (as far as I can tell) to
> be generating declarations in TypeScript project – you can just link
> the source code. The benefit of this approach is that if you click on
> 'slonik' package in your IDE, it will take you directly to src rather
> than a generated .d.ts file.
>
> Maybe someone will educate me on the reason why declaration are even
> necessary, but for now it appears that not generating declarations
> should be preferred as it achieves better DX.
>
> Just adopted the same pattern for Turbowatch and it appears to produce
> the desired DX.

https://github.com/gajus/slonik/pull/474

[Comments on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/typescript/comments/11swbpu/til_that_you_dont_shouldnt_be_generating/) say that `.d.ts` files are faster to parse and should be preferred over `.ts`. Is there any documentation elaborating on the difference between the two (in terms of parsing) and the performance penalty of using one over the other?

Comment: "Link the source code"? What does that even mean? You need to generate declaration files and ship them with the generated JavaScript files. You should not be shipping your TypeScript source to users of the library. Also, why would linking to the source even be useful? It'll just be a mess since end-users of your library only want to know what the signatures of functions are or the types of certain objects. They don't care about the implementation. The whole point of a library is to abstract away the implementation.

Comment: As for "are .d.ts files faster to parse?", I did some googling and I found that they are faster, which matches my expectations since they're simpler in terms of syntax. But again, why would you ever need to compare declaration files vs source files? They do different things.

Comment: Through different conversations I found a lot better way to achieve the desired result https://twitter.com/kuizinas/status/1636641120477384705